# Using OR operator to match the string in php

Tags: php

I am getting past of speech in result. I kept condition to feed noun and adjectives on one array like this:

```
function printTag($tags) {
        $var  = array();
        foreach($tags as $t) {
                echo $t['token'] . "/" . $t['tag'] .  " ";
                if($t['tag'] == 'NN'|| $t['tag']== 'JJ'){
                        array_push($var, $t['token'])   ;
                }
        }
        return $var;
}
```

but it does not give correct result:

My out put for echo is this :

```
The/DT quick/JJ brown/JJ fox/NN
 jumped/VBD over/IN the/DT lazy/JJ
 dog./NN this/DT is/VBZ really/RB yummy/JJ and/CC excellent/JJ
 pizza/NN
 I/NN have/VBP seen/VBN have/VBP really/RB in/IN love/NN it/PRP
 it/PRP
```

when I do var_dump($var), it gives:

```
 array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "quick"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "brown"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "dog."
  [3]=>
  string(5) "yummy"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "I"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "love"
}
```

why some noun and adjectives skipped?

Comment: try comparing with trim($t['tag']) == 'NN' and for JJ as well.

Comment: thanks @Tuim, you can write your answer even for this

Comment: Looks like line end characters cause the problem. Trim is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the string you are comparing might have endline or whitespace characters in it.

This can be resolved by using the following:

```
trim($t['tag']) == 'NN'
```

This is generally a good idea when comparing strings.